# Números aleatorios con probabilidades distintas

Tags: algoritmos

Mi pregunta no es sobre un lenguaje en especifico sino más bien como se resuelve un problema.

Como puedo generar números aleatorios pero con diferentes probabilidad de que salgan, por ejemplo,

> 5 --> 63%
>
> 10 -->  29,99%
>
> 25 --> 7%
>
> 50 -->    0,01%
>
> 80 --> 0,0001%

Los porcentajes los saque de un juego a modo de ejemplo nada más.

Comment: Tienes una lista definida de los valores que quieres que salgan? Si es así una posible solución es crear un array con los posibles valores y que aparezcan tantas veces en el array como indique su probabilidad. Si por ejemplo tienes 3 valores (20, 50, 70) con probabilidad (10%, 50 %, 40%) puedes crear el array [20, 50, 50, 50, 50 , 50, 70, 70, 70, 70] y usas la función ranfom() (o equivalente) para obtener posiciones del array.

Comment: @MrSman Ese método es válido para probabilidades "razonables", pero las que pone el OP en su ejemplo no lo son tanto... Ya que el 80 debe aparecer con probabilidad de 0,0001%, eso significa una vez de cada millón... así que el método que propones necesitaría una lista con un millón de elementos

Comment: @abulafia tienes toda la razón pero podría hacerse incluso sin tener que crear el array en sí mismo ya que en el caso de 1 millón de valores basta con almacenar el valor y el rango de indices que abarcaría en el array. Pero igual me gusta la solución que propones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El compañero @abulafia se me ha adelantado, pero como ya había preparado un código en C# que demostraba el método, pues lo dejo por aquí.

Básicamente, el método es el mismo. Se trata de:

1- Tener dos colecciones de igual tamaño, una con los valores, y otra con las probabilidades

2- Se computan los pesos acumulados,es decir, para cada posición de array, se coloca el valor de la posición mas la suma de los anteriores.

3- Se obtiene un numero aleatorio entre 0 y la suma de los valores de los pesos (idealmente,1)

4- Se obtiene el indice del primer valor mayor que el número aleatorio obtenido, y ese es el índice del valor que se selecciona.

Vamos con el código:

```
Random rn = new Random();
//paso 1

int[] arrayvalores = new int[] { 25, 50, 75, 100 };
double[] pesos = new double[] {0.6,0.3,0.07,0.03 };

double acc=0;

//paso 2
double[] pesosAcumulados = pesos.Aggregate((IEnumerable<double>)new List<double>(),
            (x, i) => x.Concat(new[] { x.LastOrDefault() + i })).ToArray();

double rando = 0;

int[] resultadoaleatorio = new int[4];
for (int i=0;i<10000;i++)
{
    //paso 3
    rando = rn.NextDouble() * pesos.Sum();
    //paso 4
    int posicionArray = pesosAcumulados.ToList().IndexOf(pesosAcumulados.Where(x => x > rando).FirstOrDefault());
    resultadoaleatorio[posicionArray]++;
}

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Indice {i} - peso {pesos[i]} - veces que ha salido {resultadoaleatorio[i]} - porcentaje {(resultadoaleatorio[i]*100/10000)/100.0}");
}
```

Como ves en este ejemplo, hago la tirada aleatoria 10000 veces para ver si el método funciona correctamente. Este es un ejemplo de la salida de una ejecución:

```
Indice 0 - peso 0,6 - veces que ha salido 6043 - porcentaje 0,6
Indice 1 - peso 0,3 - veces que ha salido 2992 - porcentaje 0,29
Indice 2 - peso 0,07 - veces que ha salido 670 - porcentaje 0,06
Indice 3 - peso 0,03 - veces que ha salido 295 - porcentaje 0,02
```

Como ves, este método se ajusta bastante bien a los porcentajes de entrada.

Answer (score 8):

Un método bastante genérico sería tener en una estructura de datos (por ejemplo en dos listas separadas) los posibles números a generar y los posibles "pesos relativos" de cada uno, por ejemplo la probabilidad en tanto por ciento de que salgan.

A partir de la lista de pesos obtenemos una lista de probabilidades. Debemos asegurar que las probabilidades suman 1, por lo que en la lista que contiene esos pesos podríamos dividir cada elemento por la su suma de todos ellos.

A partir de la lista de probabilidades construimos otra lista de probabilidades "acumuladas", que son, para cada elemento, su probabilidad más la suma de todas las probabilidades anteriores.

Por ejemplo, si las listas de entrada son:

```
datos = [ 5, 10, 25, 50, 80 ]
pesos = [ 63, 29.99, 7, 0.01, 0.0001 ]
```

la de pesos "reajustados" sería:

```
probabilidades = [0.6299994, 0.2998997, 0.0699999, 0.0001000, 0.0000010]
```

y  la de probabilidades acumuladas sería:

```
acumuladas = [0.62999937, 0.92989907, 0.999899  , 0.999999  , 1.]
```

Entonces, una vez tenemos esta última, el algoritmo sería:

- Generar un número aleatorio entre 0 y 1 (p.ej: supongamos que sale el 0.8543)
- Recorrer el array  `acumuladas` y encontrar el índice del primer elemento que supere al número obtenido en el apartado anterior (en el ejemplo, el primer número que lo cumple es el 0.92989907, cuyo índice es 1)
- Seleccionar en la lista `datos` el que tenga ese índice (siguiendo con el ejemplo, el seleccionado sería `datos[1]` que es 10.

Si el primer paso genera los números aletorios uniformemente distribuidos entre 0 y 1, este algoritmo irá seleccionando los números de `datos` con las probabilidades especificadas.

### Ampliación

Por si a alguien le es útil, y para comparar con otros lenguajes, aquí va una posible implementación en Python:

```
from itertools import accumulate
import random

def elige_con_probabilidad(datos, pesos):
  suma = sum(pesos)
  pesos = accumulate(peso/suma for peso in pesos)
  r = random.random()
  for i, p in enumerate(pesos):
    if p > r:
      break
  return datos[i]
```

Para ver qué tal va, genero 10000 números aleatorios con una distribución dada y cuento cuántas veces se repite cada uno:

```
from collections import Counter

datos = [25, 50, 75, 100]
pesos = [0.6, 0.3, 0.07, 0.03]
muchos = [ elige_con_probabilidad(datos, pesos) for _ in range(10000) ]
print(Counter(muchos))
```

---

```
Counter({25: 5977, 50: 3002, 75: 707, 100: 314})
```

Answer (score 2):

Para generar variables aleatorias discretas hay dos casos: el primero ha sido ya desarrollado -**con reposición**- y el segundo es **sin reposición**.

Come se mencionó que la inspiración vino de un juego, pensé en los Naipes. Estos antes de repartirse se barajan o permutan, esto último no tiene que confundirse con el [cambio de variable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uz58hg0EJAY) o [problema de monty hall](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_de_Monty_Hall) ya que las probabilidades con cada extracción cambian.

Siguiendo con el caso de las cartas, al inicio la probabilidad de obtener cualquier carta es 1/54, al sacarse la segunda es 1/53 y así sucesivamente.

Tomado los siguientes valores de entrada

```
datos = { 5, 10, 25, 50, 80 }
probabilidades = {0.6299994, 0.2998997, 0.0699999, 0.0001000, 0.0000010}
probaAcumulada = {0.6299994,0.9298991,0.999899,0.999999,1}
```

Supongamos que necesitamos extraer tres datos.

Antes de la Primera extracción se tiene un diagrama de probabilidad acumulada, que es idéntica al caso con reposición detallada ya por varios en este *trend*.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Al generarse el número [pseudo-aleatorio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_pseudoaleatorio) 0.725... -entre 0 y 1- que cae en el eje de las ordenadas (eje y) le corresponde el número 10 de las abscisas (eje x)

Dado que el 10 sale las probabilidades restantes se suman y este resultado luego las divide a cada una de ellas... como en el ejemplo de las cartas sale una de las 54 sumo todas las restantes que da 53 y ese total divide a cada carta 1/53.

Por tanto quedaría los datos de entrada para la segunda extracción de la siguiente forma:

```
datos = { 5, 25, 50, 80 }
probaAcumulada = {0.899870204,0.999855735,0.9999985722,1}
```

Siendo su representación gráfica esta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como salé el número 5, los datos de entrada y su correspondiente gráfica de probabilidades, quedan así para una tercera extracción si se necesitara efectuarla.

```
datos = { 25, 50, 80 }
probaAcumulada = {0.99855922,0.999985735,1}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La extracción lleva el nombre de muestra y es esta cantidad la que va en un bucle -a modo de condición- hasta que se extrae los datos que se necesiten.

Resumiendo el algoritmo se puede verbalizar así:

Se tiene datos (**d**), sus probabilidades (**p**) el tamaño de muestra (**m**) y cantidad actual extraída (**q**) que al inicio es cero

```
Paso 00: Calcular las probabilidades acumuladas (`pAcum`) de `p`
Paso 01: Generar un número pseudo-aleatorio (`u`) entre 0 y 1
Paso 02: Verificar para cada pAcum cuál es la primera en superar a `u` y extraer su indice (`i`)
Paso 03: Guardar el valor de `d` correspondiente a la posición `i`
Paso 04: Remover de `d` y `p` el valor correspondiente a la posición `i`
Paso 05: Re-calcular las probabilidades acumuladas (`pAcum`) de `p`
Paso 06: Sumarle a `q` uno
Paso 07: Mientras `m>=q` volver al Paso 01
```

Una aclaración final, si la muestra es del tamaño de todos los datos, esto es equivalente a permutar los datos es decir a barajar los naipes, aunque a diferencia de estos, tu caso es interesante ya que las probabilidades son diferentes.

Una aplicación práctica de generar variables aleatorias discretas son los teclados virtuales de los bancos, donde se deben mezclar o permutar las teclas {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0} para cada sesión y/o usuario.

Aquí una implementación en Lua sobre generación de v.a. discreta con y sin reposición

```
-- funcion de ayuda
local rand = math.random

-- valores de entrada
datos = { 5, 10, 25, 50, 80 }
probabilidades = {0.6299994, 0.2998997, 0.0699999, 0.0001000, 0.0000010}


-- funcion de ayuda para sumar elementos de una tabla en Lua
table.suma = function (list, fn)
    local acc
    for k, v in ipairs(list) do
        acc = k==1 and v or fn(acc, v)
    end
    return acc
end


-- funcion para acumular probabilidades
local acumProba = function(prob)
    local r = {prob[1]}
    for i=2, #prob do r[#r+1] = prob[i]+r[i-1] end
    return r
end


-- funcion para recalcular probabilidades cuando un elemento de la
-- tabla salió elegido
-- tener cuidado con el cambio de variable en este caso esta funcion
-- puede no ser valida
local acumProbAdj = function(prob)
    local total = table.suma(prob, function(a,b) return a+b end)
    local probAdj={}
    for _,valorProb in pairs(prob) do
        probAdj[#probAdj+1] = valorProb/total
    end
    return probAdj
end


-- eleccion de elementos al azar con reposicion
local conReposicion = function(dat, prob)
    local aleatorio = rand()

    for id, probAcumulada in pairs(prob) do
        if probAcumulada>aleatorio then
            return dat[id], id
        end
    end

end


-- eleccion de elementos al azar sin reposicion
-- tener en cuenta si la cantidad de muestra es
-- igual al total de datos se obtendrá un mezcla
-- al azar de los datos originales
local sinReposicion = function(dat, prob, cantMuestra)
    local d, p = {unpack(dat)}, {unpack(prob)}
    local muestras = {}
    local muestra, id

    for i=1, cantMuestra do
        muestra, id = conReposicion(d,acumProba(p))
        table.remove(d,id); table.remove(p,id)
        p = acumProbAdj(p)
        muestras[#muestras+1] = muestra
    end

    return muestras

end


-------------------------------------------
-- EJEMPLOS
-------------------------------------------

-- se obtiene las probabilidades acumuladas
print("\nSe obtiene las probabilidades acumuladas")
print(unpack(acumProba(probabilidades)))
print("\nPara los datos")
print(unpack(datos))



-- se obtiene solo un resultado de los datos al azar
print("\nCon resposición: se obtiene solo un resultado de los datos al azar. \nSe intenta 16 veces")
for i=1,16 do
    print("Intento "..i.." >",({conReposicion(datos,acumProba(probabilidades))})[1])
end




-- sin reposición para una muestra de 2, 3 y de 5 datos = #datos
-- cuando es 5 es equivalente a permutar o barajar los datos
print("\nSin reposición: para una muestra de 3, 2, 5, 1 y 4")
local a = {3, 2, 5, 1, 4}
for _,id in pairs(a) do
    print(id..">",unpack(sinReposicion(datos,probabilidades,id)))
end




-- Ejemplo de teclado virtual de banco
-- Creamos los valores de entrada, todos los números:
-- 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 tienen la misma probabilidad 1/10
local p,n={},{}
for i=1, 10 do table.insert(p,i,1/10); table.insert(n,i,i) end
n[#n]=0

-- Se permutan los números
local a = sinReposicion(n,p,10)

print("\nImprimimos teclado Virtual\n",
    "\n",a[1],a[2],a[3],
    "\n",a[4],a[5],a[6],
    "\n",a[7],a[8],a[9],
    "\n",a[10],"Ingresar"
)
```

Puedes ejecutar el código Lua aquí en [replit](https://repl.it/repls/LimitedNauticalGraph)

Finalmente los gráficos los realicé en R, el código fuente está en [replit](https://repl.it/repls/WhichGargantuanBusinesssoftware), pero su edición la realicé en [Skitch](https://evernote.com/products/skitch).