# como obtener 4 numeros random distintos pero con la misma probabilidad en java?

Tags: java

mi pregunta se trata en generar 4 numeros random de un rango determinado por mi, pero estos 4 numeros nunca deben ser iguales, es decir tengo que intentar obtener 4 numeros siempre con la misma probabilidad para ello diseñe este codigo

```
        int posicion=-1;
        int contador=0;
        
        while (contador<4) {
            
            random = (int)(Math.random()*20);
            
            if (random != posicion){
                
            System.out.println(random);
            
            posicion=random;
            
            contador++;
            
            }
            
            
        }
```

como pueden ver inicializo el primer numero random que obviamente es unico, luego tengo una variable llamada posicion que esta tendria un valor inicial imposible para que la primera vez del condicional pueda mostrar el primer numero aleatoria que obviamente no se repite por ser el primero. ademas tengo un bucle para limitar la cantidad de numeros random que es 4 y que esta condicion solo aumenta cuando entra en el condicional if y si entra en el condicional la variable posicion toma el valor de random para guardar el ultimo valor aleatoria que salio y vuelve a ejecutarse la funcion random, de esta forma si al evaluar el if no es distinto el numero aleatorio del anterior, se ejecutara el while tantas veces hasta que salta un numero aleatorio diferente. EL PROBLEMA es que una ves que encuentre los primero 2 numeros aleatorios diferentes, cuando busque el tercero, este sera comparado con el segundo y el primer numero se perdio, por lo que podria salir el mismo numero entre la poscicion 1 y 3, o el 2 y 4 o el 1 y 4. por ejemplo
[1 ; 2 ; 1 ; 2 ]   Alguna sugerencia ??  Muchas gracias por leer.

Comment: Revisa el siguiente [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/235999/193364)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encontre la forma dejo el codigo por las dudas le sirva a alguien, puse un rango de aleatoridad en "5", osea muy pequeño para que salgan los 4 numero exacto para ver si alguno repetia, porque mientras mas grande sea el rango mas dificil es probar si sale numeros repetidos

```
    int posicion[]=new int [4];
    int i=0;
    
    posicion[i] = (int)(Math.random()*5);
    
    for (i=1; i<4;i++) {
        
        posicion[i]= (int)(Math.random()*5);
        
        for(int j=0; j<i;j++) {
        
           if (posicion[i] == posicion[j]){
            i--;
           }
        }
    }
    
    
    for (int k=0; k < 4 ; k++) {
        
        System.out.println(posicion[k]);
    }
```

Comment: Esto es demasiado complejo para resolver un problema muy sencillo. Si deseas generar `n` valores aleatorios de un rango dado, usas una lista con dicho rango, la desordenas y tomas los primeros `n`. No necesitas estar comparando con los ya generados ni hacer bucles dobles. Por ejemplo, si deseo obtener 4 valores aleatorios en el rango 1 al 100, genero una lista de números del 1 al 100, luego desordeno (barajo) dicha lista y por último tomo 4 valores de cualquier posición de la lista, es decir, los primeros 4 o los últimos 4 o 4 del medio o 4 diferentes en cualquier posición existente. Saludos

Comment: Se me olvidó mencionar que para desordenar (barajar) una lista se usa algún algoritmo. Por lo general se usa el [Algoritmo de Fisher - Yates](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Fisher-Yates). Adicionalmente en Java también dispones de la utilidad Collections que dispone del método [`shuffle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) que desordena una lista de forma aleatoria. Saludos