# Ruleta de probabilidades

Tags: python, random

soy nuevo en python, estoy intentando hacer que esta lista de nombres tenga una probabilidad dada, por ejemplo, que Juan tenga un 40% de probabilidad de salir, que Pedro tenga el 20% y así sucesivamente, me gustaría saber que funciones puedo usar para hacer dicha tarea, gracias.

```
import random
lista_nombres = ["Juan", "Pedro", "Luis", "Daniel", "Carlos"]
ganador = random.randint(0,len(lista_nombres)-1)
print("El ganador es: " + lista_nombres[ganador])
```

Comment: genera un número aleatorio entre 0-99. Si el número es menor a 40, eliges el primer nombre de la lista. Si el número es menor a 60 (40 + 20), eliges el segundo nombre. Y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Como han expuesto los compañeros, con [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices), puedes resolver el problema; solo que ¡advertencia! para los usuarios de versiones antiguas, funciona para Python 3.6 o superior. En el caso que quieras construir un algoritmo, también puedes mirar [Esta Pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/235990/80870) en el sitio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar [random.choices()](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/random.html#random.choices) y con `weights` indicarle el peso que tiene cada alternativa en que sea elegida.

```
import random

lista_nombres  = ["Juan", "Pedro", "Luis", "Daniel", "Carlos"]
print(random.choices(lista_nombres , weights=(40, 20, 15, 10, 10), k=1))
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!

Comment: Una pregunta, con la K que indicas?

Comment: La cantidad de elecciones, te retorna una lista si le indicas más de 1. En la documentación del enlace está explicado.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `random.choices` limitando el numero de elecciones a una y usar `weights` o `cum_weights`:

```
import random

lista_nombres = ["Juan", "Pedro", "Luis", "Daniel", "Carlos"]
pesos = (0.4, 0.2, 0.18, 0.12, 0.10)
ganador = random.choices(lista_nombres, weights=pesos)[0]
print(f"El ganador es: {ganador}")
```

O usando `cum_weights`:

```
pesos_acum = (0.4, 0.6, 0.78, 0.90, 1.0)
ganador = random.choices(lista_nombres, cum_weights=pesos_acum)[0]
```

Fuera de la stdlib puedes usar [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

```
import numpy as np


lista_nombres = ["Juan", "Pedro", "Luis", "Daniel", "Carlos"]
pesos = (0.4, 0.2, 0.18, 0.12, 0.10)
ganador = np.random.choice(lista_nombres, p=pesos)
print(f"El ganador es: {ganador}")
```

aunque si no usas NumPy en tu proyecto para otras cosas es un poco "matar moscas a cañonazos".

Otra opción implementar el algoritmo directamente, podemos implementar una versión simplificada de [la usada en `random.choices`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/872c0714fcdc168ce4a69bdd0346f2d5dd488ec2/Lib/random.py#L458):

1. Calcular las probabilidades acumuladas (si no las proporcionas directamente).
2. Generar número aleatorio entre 0 y 1 con `random.random()`.
3. Buscar en la lista de probabilidades acumuladas la probabilidad mas cercana mayor al numero aleatorio y obtenemos el indice de esta probabilidad en la lista.
4. Usamos el indice para indizar sobre la lista de nombres y obtener el ganador.

`itertools.accumulate` nos solventa el primer paso y `bisect.bisect` nos brinda justo lo que necesitamos para el tercero:

```
from bisect import bisect
from itertools import accumulate
from random import random


lista_nombres = ["Juan", "Pedro", "Luis", "Daniel", "Carlos"]
pesos = (0.4, 0.2, 0.18, 0.12, 0.10)
random_index = bisect(tuple(accumulate(pesos)), random())
ganador = lista_nombres[random_index]
print(f"El ganador es: {ganador}")
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias